# Searching multiple mysql tables with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I know this has been covered however I'm struggling to get this to work. My DB structure is as follows:

**Photo**

```
id
title
description
file_name
```

**Photo_Category**

```
id
photo_id
category_id
```

**Categories**

```
id
name
```

**Tags**

```
id
tag_name
```

**Photo_Tags**

```
id
photo_id
tag_id
```

What I'm trying to do is allow someone to type in a phrase or keyword and then I search the Database for results that possibly match in tags, categories, and of course the photo title and description and return the Photo data for the results.

If it helps i'm developing in codeigniter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what have you tried.?

Comment: plz support new users they are not intelligent as well all our

Comment: do you get the answer.?

Comment: Yeah I got the answer from you Adarsh :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
As my understand with your question

The function in model

function example($phrase)  //select position
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('photo');
        $this->db->join('phototags', 'phototags.photo_id = photo.id', 'left');
                $this->db->join('tags', 'tags.id = phototags.tag_id', 'left');
                $this->db->join('Photo_Category', 'Photo_Category.photo_id = photo.id', 'left');
                $this->db->join('Categories', 'Categories.id = Photo_Category.category_id', 'left');
        $this->db->like('tag_name' , $phrase, 'after');
                $this->db->like('Categories.name' , $phrase, 'after');
                $this->db->like('photo.title' , $phrase, 'after');
                $this->db->like('photo.description' , $phrase, 'after');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```